# Windows 10 weekly update how to cancel?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Lenovo laptop with a 60% full 512Gb SSD on a 100mbps internet connection. It has been running Win10 since last year.

This morning the login text box would not appear. I went to the item in the lower right to restart but that option was gone and replaced with update and shut down. Normally this takes a couple of minutes and there seemed to be no other option so I did it.

That was 45 minutes ago and it’s at 30%. I have looked for posts about cancelling this but they all assume you are logged in and can get to the task manager.

So can I just force restart?

Comment: forced restart is not adviced but if you really need then it cant be avoided

Comment: Windows is already partially updated. Cancelling at this point will leave it broken.

Comment: I would let it grind away, it could take many hours to complete depending on your system specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you to not do this because I suffered badly on my SurfacePro4 on two occasions when I did a forced shutdown.

- On the first occasion I got a complete black screen on startup. It means that the harddrive won't load windows. I had reinstall windows then.
- On another occasion I got a blue screen with haphazard error messages all over it. Then I was good with only doing a repair.

So I would request you to be patient and
wait unless you are quite lucky to not corrupt your windows.
Once you are ON you might want to go to services.msc through the Wi+R(Run)
command and disable the windows update service down below.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to go to the recovery environment open command prompt and type something like:

**Dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions**

Comment: I don't think this is advisable if it is in the middle of upgrading the OS.

Comment: This would require the author to forcefully shutdown the machine.  The author is clearly in a situation, more than likely, where a feature update is actually being installed instead of a cumulative update.

Comment: @Ramhound - indeed. If they SIMPLY TOLD ME THAT I'd be fine, but there was zero indication this was anything other than a weekly patch. Bad MS, no donut!

Comment: @user1469457 - Pending feature updates are shown in the same location as any other pending update is shown though.  In fact notifications are generated that a feature update is being installed typically since, a good chunk of the work is performed while Windows is running and before it is rebooted.